# Why is there an unlit campfire under Tabantha Bridge Stable's well?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I was exploring the well near Tabantha Bridge Stable, and I came across an unlit campfire underground.
What's its purpose? Is there any reason for this? I tried igniting it, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's remnants of the wandering Chef who's been going around Hyrule, living in Wells, and recording notes and recipes in his journals! (It's why you also sometimes find journals inside wells)

There's nothing special about this campfire in particular that I'm aware of, but you find evidence of these "inhabited wells" fairly regularly throughout the region.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about the wandering chef who used to live in wells! But I didn't find any note inside it.